# Bash error: find: I cannot figure out how to interpret ‘2018-26-01’ as a date or time

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

I have a journal backup which runs 5 times a day.

```
2.1G -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.1G Jan 25 03:50 xxxxxxx.jrnl.428612
514M -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 512M Jan 25 11:50 xxxxxxx.jrnl.428629
2.1G -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.1G Jan 25 19:50 xxxxxxx.jrnl.428664
 18M -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  18M Jan 25 20:32 xxxxxxx.jrnl.428699
194M -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 193M Jan 25 23:50 xxxxxxx.jrnl.428704
```

I have the beginnings of a script that will be run at 04:00 to copy the file created between
03:45 and 03:55 to a subdirectory labeled '1'.

```
 #!/bin/bash

 # Daily Journal Backup Number 1 

 # Establish target directory
DIRsource="/mnt/Backup/INCREMENTAL/*"
DIRdestination="/mnt/Backup/Yesterday/JOURNAL/1"

 # Calculate the current date, concatenate with specific target time
TIMESTART="$(date '+%Y'-'%d'-'%m') 03:45:00"    # $TIMESTART returns 2018-25-01 03:45:00
TIMESTOP="$(date '+%Y'-'%d'-'%m') 03:55:00" # $TIMESTOP  returns 2018-25-01 03:55:00

 # If the destination directory is not empty, delete all files in it.
if [ "$(ls -A $DIRdestination)" ]; then
    # "Take action $DIRdestination is not empty"
    rm -f $DIRdestination/*

 # Look for the files which have a modify time between 20:25:00 and 20:45:00 on the prior day
find $DIRsource -type f -newermt $TIMESTART ! -newermt $TIMESTOP -exec cp --preserve=timestamps {} $DIRdestination/ \;
```

I get this error when the script runs:

```
find: I cannot figure out how to interpret ‘2018-26-01’ as a date or time
```

How do I fix this interpretation issue?

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: @Cyrus Would that really detect this problem? It's not a shell syntax error.

Comment: No but it will point out other rampant errors in this script (including the wacky indent by one space which wrecks the shebang line).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 things which I could notice on very first glance.

***1st:*** your `if` condition is NOT properly closed add `fi` to close it after your `rm` statement.

***2nd:*** Wrap your variables in `find` command in double quotes as follows:

```
find "$DIRsource" -type f -newermt "$TIMESTART" ! -newermt "$TIMESTOP" -exec cp --preserve=timestamps {} $DIRdestination/ \;
```

***3rd:*** Thanks to Barmar sir, change your date format to `YYYY-MM-DD` format.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48466633/5866580

Comment: double quotes around $TIMESTART and $TIMESTOP was the key of the solution for me

Answer (score 3):

Dates should be in the order year-month-day, not year-day-month. So change it to:

```
TIMESTART="$(date '+%Y-%m-%d 03:45:00')"
TIMESTOP="$(date '+%Y-%m-%d 03:55:00')"
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Ravinder! I actually identified the 1st and 2nd items late Friday afternoon. I also discovered the issue listed in your 3rd item but I also changed the dashes to slashes.

```
TIMESTART="$(date '+%m'/'%d'/'%Y 06:30:00')" 
TIMESTOP="$(date '+%m'/'%d'/'%Y 06:45:00')"
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for letting us know, it will help people for sure, keep sharing and keep learning. Cheers :)